# Custom title bar code breaking onCreate()

Tags: android

I made a custom title bar that I want to appear over all the Activities in my app.    It works perfectly in my main activity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
```

But my main activity invokes another activity and when I try to do the **same** thing there it fails:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
```

Attempts to do a *findViewById()* crash and I wrapped one in a try/catch to see what was happening:

```
TextView tv1;
try {    
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header);
}
catch (Exception e)  {
    Log.d("MyActivity2", "boom");  
}
```

The exception says 
*cause=ClassCastException
detailMessage=android.widget.RelativeLayout*

I have no idea what this means and **N.B.** that there are **no** problems if I comment out  the *requestWindowFeature()* and *getWindow()* calls.

Thanks in advance for any insights into this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a ClassCastException that means R.id.header is not a TextView . In your layout `header` is the name for Relativelayout. So change this to match that of TextView.

Comment: In the Layout for Activity2 "header" is a TextView.   In the Title bar "header" is a RelativeLayout.   But since I'm accessing "header" in the onCreate() routine of the Activity2 I would think the name-scope would be for Activity2, and if not then it would have been captured at build-time.   But I'll try changing the name to avoid namespace collision.

Comment: OK, I changed the name of the RelativeLayout in the title bar to "title_rlayout" and it worked.    I posted a new question to clarify the scoping rules for XML resource Id's in Android:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988772/what-is-the-scope-of-androidid